# Does vs2012 support working with Framework 1.1

Tags: .net, winforms, frameworks, visual-studio-2012, .net-1.1

We have some legacy 2003 Winforms framework 1.1 code

i know you can set target framework etc

Would there be any other problems or changes so that we could refactor a Winforms 1.1 application ?

We have some very old Janus custom controls as part of the solution..will there be problems getting these to work or install ..or can we just have them as normal reference librarys ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: For working with old Visual Studio 2003 projects, I've set up an separate VMware image with Windows XP, Visual Studio 2003 and the like.

Comment: Imho you have to run the older Visual Studio version parallel to this. I run 2003, 2005, 2008 and 2010 parallel on one machine. Works fine at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a business not a technical question. How much money is your company prepared to invest in legacy software? Is there quantifiable benefit?

I tried porting a moderate-sized C# asp.net 1.1 website to .Net 2.0, and in the end I couldn't justify continuing; I had too much rework and too much re-testing. It wasn't worth it from a business and risk POV. The website was turning over > 1M USD a month -- making my life a little easier just wasn't worth it; I couldn't put together a business case that made any sense.

You know your situation better than us, but I would suggest you consider the timeless adage, if it ain't broke, don't fix it.